# Get large dataset of Tweets on rare subject using Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to get a large dataset of Tweets, containing keyword 'IAmsterdam' (Amsterdam's city marketing campaign).
I tried to use both the streaming API for Twitter as well as the REST API, but I'm not able to get a large data set which I could analyse (Sentiment classification)

Does anyone of you know how I can possibly get more Tweets about IAmsterdam?

**Code REST API:**

```
from TwitterSearch import *
import time
import sys
import codecs

#change to more convenient output type (utf-8)
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)

try:
    tso = TwitterSearchOrder()
    tso.set_keywords(['IAmsterdam'])
    tso.set_language('en')



    ts = TwitterSearch(
        consumer_key = '6ZnWpt6HZ1kOVSEjfFwUnLia6',
        consumer_secret = .... ,
         access_token = '2815625730-qSoq6TWyfzqpPJvY71DNAQwGUAfoQu23KgLcPg1',
         access_token_secret = ...
)

    sleep_for = 60 # sleep for 60 seconds
    last_amount_of_queries = 0 # used to detect when new queries are done


    for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
        print( '@%s tweeted: %s' % ( tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet['text'] ) )

        current_amount_of_queries = ts.get_statistics()[0]
        if not last_amount_of_queries == current_amount_of_queries:
            last_amount_of_queries = current_amount_of_queries
            time.sleep(sleep_for)

except TwitterSearchException as e:
    print(e)
```

**code STREAMING API**

```
import time, sys, codecs

#Import the necessary methods from tweepy library
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)

#Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
access_token = "2815625730-qSoq6TWyfzqpPJvY71DNAQwGUAfoQu23KgLcPg1"
access_token_secret = ....
consumer_key = "6ZnWpt6HZ1kOVSEjfFwUnLia6"
consumer_secret = ....


#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            #print data
            tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
            print tweet

            saveThis = str('')+ tweet #saves time+actual tweet
            saveFile = open('amsiams6415.txt','a')
            saveFile.write(saveThis)
            saveFile.write('\n')
            saveFile.close()
            return True
        except BaseException, e:
            print 'failed ondata,',str(e)
            time.sleep(5)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    #This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'Amsterdam'
    stream.filter(track=['IAmsterdam'], languages=['en'])
```

Comment: Are you asking what you can do to get more data?

Comment: The reason is that, you are filtering tweets using a `filter` and it depends upon the users, so either you should more keywords or you must wait till you get enough data.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to get more data.

Comment: The only way to get more data is to pull it from the real-time API or purchase access to historical data from a provider.

Answer (score 1):

No need for code samples here :).

The problem with the rest api is that it only provides 6-9 days of tweets. The streaming api will only give you tweets as they happen. So in both cases you are going to have to collect data over a longer period of time to get a large data set.

Or you'll have to make your search less restrictive and search on additional hashtags/keywords.

If you want to build up a large data-set quickly and/or to get historical data, then you can use something like http://topsy.com/ which gives you tweets going back to the beginning of twitter time. This is a paid service (there are others).

Answer (score 0):

the data you get from the API are the same as you could see if you were using [advanced search](https://twitter.com/search-advanced)
It seems there aren't many tweets using the term 'IAmsterdam' just a few per hour as I can see, furthermore you make the search more restrictive by specifying lang=en so may be you can try:

1. include more terms in your search as anmol-uppal suggested
2. remove the lang=en specification

*Also I would suggest you change the authorization tokens, since although you erased those, still remained enough time here for someone to copy or to be stored in a web search cache.*